# go protocol buffer set up wrong?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am trying to follow the instructions from https://github.com/golang/protobuf and 
https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases to install protocol buffer. After I added the bin path from the download folder to `$PATH`, I tried to run `protoc-gen-go`, but it shows `-bash: protoc-gen-go: command not found`

Is there a way to tell if I have install the protobuf correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please repeat all steps:

```
go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
nano ~/.profile
```

check/add to the end (I don't use GOROOT)

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

reload profile (for sure)

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

try now

```
protoc --go_out=. *.proto
```